# show most viewed post

Tags: wp-query, loop, post-meta, meta-query

I have blog post counts which happen when a user views a blog post via ajax and the rest api.

In the database I have a meta key and value like so:

```
table: wp_postmeta
post_id: blog post ID
meta_key: blog_post_count
meta_value: number ie: 1, 2, 3 etc.
```

This basically stores the blog post ID and the count. On a page, I am trying to display the ID with the highest count only.

```
$views = new WP_Query( array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'blog_post_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
) );
```

Running this in a standard wordpress loop however displays all posts and not with the highest count first so my Query is obviously not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
try changing 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'  to 'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num'
```